# How to scale down an image to a maxSize?

Tags: c#, image, scale

What I want is to redure picture size to 480k pixels or less for any picture with size greater than 480k pixels;

```
-- maxSize = 480k
-- picture1.Size = 1600*300 = 480k = maxSize => that's OK.
-- picture2.Size = 2600*200 = 520k => problem (should be reduced to maxSize or less).

picture2.Size / maxSize = 1.083

picture2.Size/1.083 = 480148 (~= maxSize) => that's OK.
```

Let's suppose that 1.083 is the ratio for picture resizing:
ratio = 1.083;

How to apply this ratio to keep picture aspect ratio?

Comment: Metro? WinForms? WPF? Silverlight? Windows Phone? ASP.Net? MonoTouch?

Comment: I don't care about width or height, all I care is size which should not exceed 800x600

Comment: You mean the image should not exceed 480,000 pixels?

Comment: yes tha's right, 480 000 pixels is the maximum

Comment: You say `picture2.Size/1.083 = 480148 (~= maxSize) => that's OK.` Either over 480,000 is your limit or it is not, if "about 480k" is ok you need to define what "about" is. Can we be 1 over, 10 over, 100 over, 1k over, 10k over, ...?

Answer (score 1):

You just want to solve the system:

```
newWidth * newHeight = maxSize;
newWidth / newHeight = picture2.Width / picture2.Height
```

and the solution is :

```
double newWidth = Math.Sqrt(picture2.Width * maxSize / picture2.Height);
double newHeight = Math.Sqrt(picture2.Height * maxSize / picture2.Width);
```

this way, the aspect ratio of `picture2` will be preserved, and the size won't exceed `maxSize`

Answer (score 0):

(2600-x)/(200-y) = 2600/200
and 
x*y = 1.083

Now the picture can be rescaled to a size less than maxSize and aspect ratio also remains the same.